# relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__gmpn_invert_limb' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c, linux

I am making a shared library which required libgmp.
My target is to embedded static libgmp into my shared library.

I have tried ./configure with CFLAGS="-fPIC".
In addition, I have also tried modifying all Makefile in subdir of libgmp source to compile all code with -fPIC. (dirty work)

However, I still got the error message when I linking libgmp.a to my shared library.

/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libgmp.a(divrem_1.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `__gmpn_invert_limb' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC

How can I create a static libgmp.a which can be linked into my shared library?
Thank you.

Comment: Please show your (1) configure line and things leading up to it like `CFLAGS`; (2) configuration summary from Autotools and (3) the command line used for `divrem_1.c`.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
./configure --with-pic
```